# how to avoid Zero-width unbreakable space in php

Tags: php, html, linux, encoding, utf-8

My website renders `&#65279` to the HTML 
I tried saving the file encoded UTF-8 without BOM and all those solution but i am still getting the error

Note: i have Arabic characters and working on windows when hosting environment is Linux

Comment: ...delete the spaces from the source file?

Comment: Post sample code and/or a URL. As posed, the question looks unanswerable.